# How to get bundle ID for IOS and Android using react native expo

Tags: xcode, react-native, bundle, vue-native

I have created a vue-native application and need to gather the Bundle ID for IOS as well as Android but am unable to open my project in Xcode. How can I go about accessing this information? Thanks

Answer (score 5):

I'm passing through the same process. I'm using

```
"ios": {
  "supportsTablet": true,
  "bundleIdentifier": "bundlename",
  "infoPlist": {
    "NSCameraUsageDescription": "This app uses the camera to scan barcodes on event tickets."
  }
},
"android": {
  "package": "pckname",
  "versionCode": 15
}
```

inside the expo graphs in `app.json`.
You can get further info here for building standalone apps: https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/distribution/building-standalone-apps